# Git post-receive hook live output stream

Tags: git, nginx, fastcgi

I am hosting a git-http-backend with nginx and fastCGI (fcgiwrap). When I push my application, which has a post-receive hook, it seems like only after the termination of the hook the output is being sent to my git client.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

echo "foo"
sleep 5
echo "bar"
```

Somewhere it buffers the output after the termination and sends it at once. So it will take be 5 seconds to actually see "foo". I am not quite sure where this buffering is happening.

I think that what I want is possible, as Heroku for example is also able to stream the output of their post-receive hook.

This is my `nginx.conf`:

```
user                    nginx;
worker_processes        4;
pid                     /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections    1024;
}

http {
    sendfile              on;
    tcp_nopush            on;
    tcp_nodelay           on;
    keepalive_timeout     65;
    types_hash_max_size   2048;

    include               /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type          application/octet-stream;

    access_log            /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log             /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip                  on;
    gzip_disable          "msie6";

    server {
        server_name       _;
        listen 80         default_server;
        listen [::]:80    default_server;

    location /ping {
        add_header Content-Type text/plain;
        return 200 'pong';
    }

    location ~ ^.*\.git/objects/([0-9a-f]+/[0-9a-f]+|pack/pack-[0-9a-f]+.(pack|idx))$ {
        root            /var/lib/git;
    }

    location ~ ^.*\.git/(HEAD|info/refs|objects/info/.*|git-(upload|receive)-pack)$ {
        client_max_body_size            0;
        include         fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend;
        fastcgi_param   GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL "";
        fastcgi_param   GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /var/lib/git;
        fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO $uri;
        fastcgi_param   REMOTE_USER $remote_user;
        fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
        fastcgi_buffering off;
        fastcgi_keep_conn on;
    }

        location / {
            try_files       $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
    }


}


daemon                  off;
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason was neither git nor nginx, but fastcgi. I found this article helpful: https://serverfault.com/questions/852564/nginx-and-fcgiwrap-incremental-output-problems.

However the patch provided was only for Debian. As I am using Alpine I ended up compiling my own binary based on https://github.com/petercolberg/fcgiwrap/tree/unbuffered

After that all I had to do was add the following line to my nginx configuration:

`fastcgi_param NO_BUFFERING 1;`